# solaris tar for files > 8G

Tags: solaris, large-files, tar

I made an archive of 19G size in Solaris10 with **tar E** option. But now neither  **tar tvf** nor **tar xvf** on the tarball works!! How can I extract the files?

Comment: Nope. The commands return without displaying or doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried GNU tar (`gtar`)? There is a solaris SFW package for this `SUNWgtar` or try SunFreeware.

From the `tar(1)` man page:

```
 See largefile(5) for the description of the behavior of  tar
 when  encountering  files greater than or equal to 2 Gbyte (
 2^31 bytes).
```

On my Solaris 10 system `largefile(5)` says that `tar` is `largefile`-aware.

Perhaps `truss` can help:

```
truss -a -f -o /tmp/truss.out tar xf foo.tar
```

(please post `truss.out` if it's not too long, or perhaps just the tail of it otherwise).

**EDIT**: I just stumbled across patches 138621-02/138622-02, "SunOS 5.10: tar patch" from June 2010. In particular, fixes bug "6578528 /usr/bin/tar dumps core when extracting large files". (This is not a Recommended or Security patch so could have been missed).

Comment: I just figured that the problem happens only when I try to tar a folder which has files > 8G in size. If I tar up only the files it works just fine!

Comment: Wild! That sounds like a bug to me :(